# Latex Fancyhdr For Specific Page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, report

I am writing a report with a number of chapters. I would like each chapter to have a figure above the name of it, which differs depending on a chapter. I got a figure to display above the chapter name, but the problem is that the figure will be applied to every page of this specific chapter. I would like the figure to appear **only** above the chapter name.

I have slightly modified an example from the Overleaf website:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{80.0pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-80.0pt}
\chead{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure1.png}}

\begin{document}
\title{Title here} 
\date{September 2013}
\author{Jesper Jensen}
\maketitle

\chapter{First Chapter Title}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-12]

\chapter{Second Chapter Title}
\fancyhead{}
\chead{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure2.png}}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Inserting a figure in the header will need a lot of space. What to do with empty space in other pages? Maybe it is better if you change the chapter head, that is, produced by the `\chapter{}`, not the header page style.

Comment: You can do that with `titlesec`.

Comment: Thank you both for the pointers, I used titlesec.

Answer (score 0):

Useful comments led to the answer by David Carlisle found here:

[Include figure on the same page above \chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211835/include-figure-on-the-same-page-above-chapter)